# How to create a composite Primary Key on a Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have created a  table, i have inserted some data as well. I have 1 primary key on the table which is incremented by auto-generated number. I have `user_id` and `semester_course_id` columns both are `foreign_keys`. I want to add composite key on 2 Columns `user_id` and `semester_course_id` .

So that 1 Student_id can register to 1 Course only. `Semester_Course_id` and `student_id` will  repeat in the table, but together they have to appear one time only.

Kindly tell me how to add composite primary key.

[image]
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do you need this as a ___primary___ composite key, or simply as a ___unique___ composite key

Comment: I want them to be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `unique` constraint on combination of both columns.

```
alter table table_name
  add constraint uk_sid_coursid
      unique key ( studentid, semistercourseid )
```

For this composite key to work as *secondary primary key*, define each of this field as `not null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD unique index(StudentId,SemisterCourseId);
```

Comment: A table can only have one `primary key`. OP said table has `'1 primary key on the table which is incremented by auto-generated number'`. So this is not going to work.

Comment: Ok. Good that you changed your solution.